# Get repeated childs in parent collection

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many, duplicates

Well, I have this design on my doctrine 2:

**Disc**

id, name

**Lyric**

id, name, artist

**list (the join table for many-to-many)**

id, disc, lyric

So, when I call $disc->getLyrics() it returns the current lyrics on disc buuut it does not allow to have the same lyric more than once. How can I deal with that?

**edit:**

at "list table" I can see the lyric stored several times for the same disc

These are my entities

Disc

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="disc")
 */
class Disc
{

/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_disc")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="name")
 */
protected $name;


/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Lyric")
 * @JoinTable(name="playlist", 
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="disc", referencedColumnName="id_disc")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="lyric", referencedColumnName="id_lyric")}
 *      )
 */ 
protected $lyrics;

public function __construct(){
    $this->lyrics = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Lyric

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="lyric")
 */
class Lyric
{

/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_lyric")
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="name")
 */
protected $name;

    /**
 * @Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="artist")
 */
protected $artist;
```

Playlist (joint table many-to-many), this is the table structure:

```
id_playlist | disc | lyric  
1           | 1    | 1  
2           | 1    | 1  
3           | 1    | 1
```

The disc 1 have the lyric 1 three times.

Comment: I guess your are talking about doctrine 1, could you paste your schema.yml ?

Comment: Look the changes. I use Doctrine 2